# How to do a reverse ip lookup and find network a visitor is coming from?

Tags: dns, ip

I'm attempting to create service that will be able to determine if or what company a user is browsing a site from. So, for example, someone who works at IBM is at their office and they visit my site. I want to know that their traffic is coming from IBM.

My knowledge of DNS is pretty basic, so I'm not really sure what doing this is called. I know it's easy enough to take an IP and find out what domain it's associated with, but what I'm trying to do isn't really the same thing.  I know Hubspot and Marketo do something like this.

Are there any available APIs that do something like this or any other good solutions? I'm willing to use a pay service. I've done googling but I'm not exactly sure what to be looking for, as everything I find just associates an IP to a website domain and not a network where a user is browsing from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reverse DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup) will get you the domain associated with the IP address.  You can do that yourself (specifics vary depending on your programming language/platform), but it will not tell you directly that the domain corresponds to a particular business.

Low-cost Geo IP providers like [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo) do a pretty good job of providing the organization (company, university, etc.) associated with the IP address (if any), at least for medium and larger organizations.  It will probably not tell you the name of a small company that connects to the internet with DSL or cable.

Comment: Cool, thank you. This looks like it does what I'm looking for